# Find the area of the parallelogram.

Tags: linear-algebra

Hit this in my book. Can someone help me out?

Let
$$
\begin{align}
u &= i - j \\
v &= 2i - 3j + k.
\end{align}
$$

Find the area of the parallelogram defined by $u$ and $v$.

Am I right to take a 3rd point $v \times u$?

Comment: You are on the right track.  The *magnitude* of the cross-product gives the area.  Do you know how to compute $v \times u$?

Comment: It's best to think about $v \times u$ as a *vector* (well, a pseudovector) rather than a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area of a parallelogram =$|\vec u \times\vec v  |$  where $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are vectors of conjugate sides of parallelogram.
$\vec u=i-j$ and $\vec v=2i-3j+k$
$$\vec u \times \vec v=
\begin{vmatrix} \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\1 & -1 & 0 \\2 & -3 & 1 \end{vmatrix}$$
$$\vec u \times \vec v=\mathbf{i}(-1-0)-\mathbf{j}(1-0)+\mathbf{k}(-3+2)$$
$$\vec u \times \vec v=\mathbf{-i}-\mathbf{j}\mathbf{-k}$$
$$|\vec u \times\vec v  |=\sqrt3$$
area of parallelogram is $\sqrt 3$

here $\mathbf{i}$,$\mathbf{j}$,$\mathbf{k}$ are unit vectors.